# window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData) throw error in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, blob

Работаю с webSocket, при получении данных с сервера - необходимо их сохранить конечному пользователю на рабочую машину.

Вот участок кода:

```
  const backendUrl = "ws://localhost:5006";
  const connection = new WebSocket(backendUrl);
  
  connection.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    const data = event.data;
    
    if(data instanceof Blob) {
      const blob = data;
      const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); // webpack throw error
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = downloadUrl;
      link.download = "fileName";
      document.append(link);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Result: ", data);
    }
  })
```

Ошибка, которую я получаю:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.string.iterator.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/web.url.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/web.url-search-params.js' in 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\frontend\src\buildJS'
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

С webpack работаю в gulp. Целевые участки кода:

```
gulp.task("build-ts", () => {
  return tsProject.src()
    .pipe(tsProject()).js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(src + "/buildJS"))
})

gulp.task("build-js", () => {
  return gulp.src(src + "/buildJS/main.js")
    .pipe(webpack({
      mode: 'development',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      watch: false,
      devtool: "source-map",
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
                  debug: true,
                  corejs: 3,
                  useBuiltIns: "usage"
                }]]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + "/scripts"))
    .on("end", browserSync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло просто снести babel-loader и подгрузить его снова